# signal generator - circularly polarised

Tags: signal, function-generator

I am testing some hardware in lab that computes the four Stokes parameters. To test the hardware, I want to generate circularly polarised sine wave. Provided the frequency is high enough (above ~100 MHz), can one use a ferrite based circulator to generate RHC/LHC polarised signals? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Hello and welcome!  You're not quite clear. Are you hoping to make a radiated circularly polarised electromagnetic wave, that you can sense with the antenna in the hardware you're testing?  Or are you just looking to produce two RF voltages 90 degrees out of phase, which you can connect to the receiver inputs?

Comment: I believe that "ferrite circulators" only work well in the GHz range, (>>100MHz).  They do distort polarization, not sure if they can actually generate RHC or LHC, (depending on what you feed in).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. What I am trying to simulate in the lab is the signal received from an antenna. If I test the hardware for the 100% linear and circular cases, I believe I can completely characterise my FPGA based Stokes computation engine. To summarise, I'd like to feed in 100% circularly polarised signal in to the hardware, and I do not have an antenna in the lab that is capable of generating/receiving circularly polarised radiation.

Comment: Wouldn't combining the received signals from a vertically polarized antenna and a horizontally polarized antenna simulate (at least partially) a circularly polarized receiving antenna?

Comment: It's been a while since I did microwave stuff, but I don't know how a circulator can give circular polarization.  Perhaps you could combine the outputs from a magic tee.  (But magic Tee 's are a wave guide component.)  It sounds like you just want the I and Q (sine and cosine) signals at 100 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Take two identical linearly polarized antennas. Orient them so that the linear polarization axes are perpendicular to each other and both antennas are perpendicular to the receiver. Now drive them with equal amplitudes, \$\pm \pi/2\$ out of phase. You should receive RH or LH circular polarization.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid radiating or receiving signals altogether and simply use a synthesiser that sweeps the signal over a frequency range. I assume that the sine wave from the synthesiser can be seen as linearly polarised, as the signal is transported by a cable to the ADCs. Again I was naively expecting that a circulator (e.g. one from Nova microwave goes all the way down to 380 MHz) can convert to RHC/LHC signals.

Comment: The concept of polarization is more or less meaningless for a signal in a coaxial cable. So no coax-based apparatus will help you here. Hollow waveguide doesn't support circular polarization either, unless it has a circular cross-section. So you have to work in free space.

Answer (score 1):

Use a signal generator with two outputs -- e.g. Siglent 1025. Configure the 2nd output with a 90 deg phase shift from the 1st.

If you can't do that, you could use 2 signal generators and trigger the 2nd from the output of the 1st.

If you can't do that, then use an all-pass filter -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pass_filter. You can also do this with two R-C networks -- one has R from the input to the output and a C to GND, the other has R & C interchanged. The two outputs will be 90 deg. out of phase, but different amplitudes unless R = 1/(2.pi.f.C).